# How to center the anchor point of a shape in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a continer whose length and width are 0, but with the animation, I change its length and width to 200. The problem is that when it starts to grow, it grows from the bottom and does not grow from the middle. I want to know how to place its anchor point in the middle. Working with after effects, they will understand by seeing this image

[image]

For example, in the code below, the circle starts growing from the bottom, while I want it to start growing from the middle point of the circle:

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late Animation<double> width;
  late AnimationController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    controller =
        AnimationController(duration: Duration(seconds: 2), vsync: this);
    width = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 200).animate(controller);
    width.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(50),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  controller.forward();
                },
                child: Text('a')),
            Container(
              width: width.value,
              height: width.value,
              decoration:
                  BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.black),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share some code?

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late Animation<double> width;
  late AnimationController controller;
  Tween<double> animation = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 200);
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    controller =
        AnimationController(duration: Duration(seconds: 2), vsync: this);
    width = animation.animate(controller);
    width.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(50),
        child: Column(
//           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                controller.forward();
              },
              child: Text('a'),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: animation.end!-width.value/2),
            Container(
              width: width.value,
              height: width.value,
              decoration:
                  BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.black),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment:  The problem is solved when we move the circle to the middle of the page. This problem is when the circle is at the bottom of the page

Answer (score -1):

I believe you have a positioning issue. I moved the circle a little bit and now it seems that it starts to grow from the center. Please let me know if this code fixes your issue:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late Animation<double> width;
  late AnimationController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    controller = AnimationController(duration: Duration(seconds: 2), vsync: this);
    width = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 200).animate(controller);
    width.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  controller.forward();
                },
                child: Text('a')),
            AnimatedContainer(
              width: width.value,
              height: width.value,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.black),
              duration: controller.duration!,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have added an example, please check it

Comment: Please let me know if the above solution works for you

Comment: I want the problem to be solved when it is spaceBetween